# How to set a length difference in chart?

Tags: chart.js

I am implementing charts and my chart looks like this.

[image]

There comes a difference of 20-40-60 but i want a difference of 0,100,200,300,400,500. How to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the Chart.js documentation on [linear scales](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html).

Set the `ticks.stepSize` for your yAxis to 100.  You may also want to set `ticks.beginAtZero` to true.

Here's a full example:

```js
{
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'Data',
        data: [602, 102, 510, 240, 680, 740, 410],
        fill: false,
      }
    ],
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [
        {
          ticks: {
            stepSize: 100,
            beginAtZero: true,
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  },
}
```

[image: Chart with custom step size]